# React: is this an acceptable way to add event listeners to a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i'm working on my first app using react and i want to attach a event listener to a component. I know theres a lot of ways to do this but i came up with this one:

```
function loginHandler () {
  alert('Hey, you clicked me!');
}

const Header = () => {
 
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <nav className="home-navbar">
        <a className="home-navbar__link home-navbar__logo" href="/">Notepp</a>
        <a className="home-navbar__link" href="/">About</a>
        <a onClick={loginHandler} className="home-navbar__link home-navbar__login" href="/">Sign in with Google</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

I don't want to transform this into a class component and create `loginHandler` method because this is just a simple nav component and i feel like it would somehow complicate thinks a bit. I'm also not sure on how to use hooks although i heard they are very useful. Of course i'm would separate my `loginHandler` function into her own file but i just want to hear from more experienced developers first. Now this being said i have actually 2 questions.

1. Is this okay to do?

On the lessons i took from React, the teachers always used class components and `onClick` to pass event listeners to components, and i decided to create my own app before learning hooks so...

2. Should i use `onClick` to handle events?

People always say its best to separate markup from interactivity and i agree with them, and seeing as onClick is at its core (i think) an HTML event handler, i'm a bit suspicious of them (don't wanna hurt my imaginary good practice points right?). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way to handle user events on elements in React. `onClick` is actually React specific and does not compile down to `onclick` in the final code but rather an `addEventListener`.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the way you do it.  You could also move the handler function into the functional component before the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, your code is fine, React itself encourages using functional components (with the addition of hooks, memo, ...).

Answer (score 1):

This is almost an exact copy of the code in the official React documentation for [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

```
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

I'd suggest at least going through "Main concepts" of the official documentation, before developing your first application. It also has a section on [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

The only remark I could make about this code is that if the `onClick` will take you to a different screen, then you might look at something like [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) so the URL changes as well.